# Time converter web page design

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let convertBtnEl = document.getElementById("convertBtn");
convertBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var hours = parseInt(document.getElementById('hoursInput').value);
    var minutes = parseInt(document.getElementById('minutesInput').value);
    var seconds = (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60;
    console.log(hours);
    var showSeconds = document.getElementById("timeInSeconds");
    var showError = document.getElementById("errorMsg");
    if (isNaN(hours) || isNaN(minutes)) {
        showError.textContent += "Error!!! Please enter any value";
    } else {
        showSeconds.textContent = "the number in seconds " + seconds;
    }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Caveat:wght@400;700&family=Lobster&family=Monoton&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap");

body {
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/dynamic-webapps/time-converter-bg.png) center/cover no-repeat fixed;
}

.converter-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-wrappers {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(209, 223, 218);
}

label {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #f5f7fa;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

button {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: rgb(18, 49, 92);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.seconds {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="converter-wrapper">
        <div class="input-wrappers">
            <label for="hoursInput">Enter the number of hours:</label>
            <input type="number" id="hoursInput">
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrappers">
            <label for="minutesInput">Enter the number of minutes:</label>
            <input type="number" id="minutesInput">
        </div>
        <button id="convertBtn">Convert</button>
        <p id="timeInSeconds" class="seconds"></p>
        <p id="errorMsg" class="error"></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When values are entered in HTML input elements with ids hoursInput and minutesInput, the HTML button with id convertBtn is clicked, the converted seconds should be shown, and the error message should be empty
**
But when we not giving value to one of the input hours or minutes they displays error text message. But when we giving values in both hours and minutes the error text message displays still showing without clearing the display message. when we enter values in hours and minutes the error text message should be clear when before we escaped on testing with only one value entered. So please help me with some code in javascript**

Comment: When values are entered in HTML input elements with ids hoursInput and minutesInput, the HTML button with id convertBtn is clicked, the converted seconds should be shown, and the error message should be empty. This was not getting Please help me

Comment: Any body please help me

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uO1f7KmPNvyPw9zNM5NUk7xLc42fhbYJ/view

Comment: Sir the above link had a Time Converter question and instruction details sir. Please go through and help me with code sir

Answer (score 2):

You're not changing back the text. And you're adding more error messages. Use this instead:

```
if (isNaN(hours) || isNaN(minutes)) {
    showError.textContent = "Error!!! Please enter any value";
} else {
    showError.textContent = " ";
    showSeconds.textContent = "the number in seconds " + seconds;
}
```

```js
let convertBtnEl = document.getElementById("convertBtn");
let hoursInput = document.getElementById('hoursInput');
let minutesinput = document.getElementById('minutesInput');

 function compute() {
  var hours = parseInt(hoursInput.value);
  var minutes = parseInt(minutesinput.value);
  var seconds = (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60;
  
  var showSeconds = document.getElementById("timeInSeconds");
  var showError = document.getElementById("errorMsg");
  if (isNaN(hours)) {
    showSeconds.style.display = "none";
    showError.style.display = "block";
    showError.textContent = "Please enter a valid number of hours";
  }
  else if (isNaN(minutes)) {
    showSeconds.style.display = "none";
    showError.style.display = "block";
    showError.textContent = "Please enter a valid number of minutes";
  }
   else {
    showError.style.display = "none";
    showSeconds.style.display = "block";
    showSeconds.textContent = "the number in seconds " + seconds;
  }
}

convertBtnEl.addEventListener("click", compute);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Caveat:wght@400;700&family=Lobster&family=Monoton&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap");
body {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/dynamic-webapps/time-converter-bg.png) center/cover no-repeat fixed;
}

.converter-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-wrappers {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 8px;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(209, 223, 218);
}

label {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f5f7fa;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: rgb(18, 49, 92);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.seconds {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="converter-wrapper">
    <div class="input-wrappers">
      <label for="hoursInput">Enter the number of hours:</label>
      <input type="number" id="hoursInput">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrappers">
      <label for="minutesInput">Enter the number of minutes:</label>
      <input type="number" id="minutesInput">
    </div>
    <button id="convertBtn">Convert</button>
    <p id="timeInSeconds" class="seconds"></p>
    <p id="errorMsg" class="error"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sir not getting expected output sir

Comment: When values are entered in HTML input elements with ids hoursInput and minutesInput, the HTML button with id convertBtn is clicked, the converted seconds should be shown, and the error message should be empty. This was not getting sir

Comment: So you want the converted seconds to be shown in real time while the user inputs?

Comment: Sir I converted into seconds sir. But i want when we entered only value in hours user input and leaved value in minutes user input it should be show error text message as "Error!!! Please enter any value" whenever we enter value in hours user input and minutes user input the error text message can be clear and dispaly only converted seconds like "the number in seconds". Please help me sir

Comment: Sir not getting sir

Comment: the seconds will display after clicking only convert button sir

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C4U14OrAlFE_3ecTsZVZQ8eXiu3g37GN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sir this is the output image sir. We leave design and layout. but want the output as like this sir

Comment: When we not entered hours user input it will show error message as "please enter valid number of hours" and when we not entered minutes user input it will show error message as "please enter valid number of minutes". If we cannot entered both hours and minutes user inputs it will displays error message as "please enter valid number of hours"

Comment: Sir not getting sir

Comment: Sir not getting expected output sir

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uO1f7KmPNvyPw9zNM5NUk7xLc42fhbYJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sir the above link had a question and instruction details sir. Please go through and help me with code sir

Comment: Sir please help me sir