# Time converter Web design page

Tags: javascript, html, css

At in javascript code, "When values are entered in HTML input elements with ids hoursInput and minutesInput, the HTML button with id convertBtn is clicked, the converted seconds should be shown, and the error message should be empty" <-How can i do this in javascript code. If i insert values in hoursInput and minutesInput, the converted seconds can be show in button with id convertBtn. How i can modify the javascript code. The converted seconds are showing seperately, but it can be show in convert button. Please help me

leave the design and layout i want converted seconds in the place of convert button when the both hours and seconds inputs was given
**Below link is the expected output**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C4U14OrAlFE_3ecTsZVZQ8eXiu3g37GN/view?usp=sharing

```js
    let convertBtnEl = document.getElementById("convertBtn");
    let hoursInput = document.getElementById('hoursInput');
    let minutesinput = document.getElementById('minutesInput');
    let secondsBtnEl = document.createElement('secondsBtn');
    
    function compute() {
        var hours = parseInt(hoursInput.value);
        var minutes = parseInt(minutesinput.value);
        var seconds = (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60;
    
        var showSeconds = document.getElementById("timeInSeconds");
        var showError = document.getElementById("errorMsg");
        if (isNaN(hours)) {
            showSeconds.style.display = "none";
            showError.style.display = "block";
            showError.textContent = "Please enter a valid number of hours";
        } else if (isNaN(minutes)) {
            showSeconds.style.display = "none";
            showError.style.display = "block";
            showError.textContent = "Please enter a valid number of minutes";
        } else {
            showError.style.display = "none";
            showSeconds.style.display = "block";
            showSeconds.textContent = seconds;
        }
    }
    
    convertBtnEl.addEventListener("click", compute);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Caveat:wght@400;700&family=Lobster&family=Monoton&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap");

body {
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/dynamic-webapps/time-converter-bg.png) center/cover no-repeat fixed;
}

.converter-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-wrappers {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(209, 223, 218);
}

label {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #f5f7fa;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

button {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: rgb(18, 49, 92);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.seconds {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="converter-wrapper">
        <div class="input-wrappers">
            <label for="hoursInput">Enter the number of hours:</label>
            <input type="number" id="hoursInput">
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrappers">
            <label for="minutesInput">Enter the number of minutes:</label>
            <input type="number" id="minutesInput">
        </div>
        <button id="convertBtn">Convert</button>
        <p id="timeInSeconds" class="seconds"></p>
        <p id="errorMsg" class="error"></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time converter web page design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563398/time-converter-web-page-design)

Comment: Yes sir. please help me